# CVE-2014-8109 and CentOS

Tags: centos, security, apache-httpd

I am going through a long list of 100s of security issues that a provider of PCI compliance security scan services reported on a client server. I have found, isolated, documented, and filed disputes for all false positives. I am unsure if I should love or hate this company. They certainly do their share to provide job security, but I'd prefer work that is a bit more interesting.

In any case, https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2014-8109 is the last item that I cannot resolve.
RedHat decided not to backport the fix to RHEL 7, and consequently, this hole was not plugged.

I am looking for advice on two things

- Can I do anything to mitigate this (a "compensating control")? Short of rebuilding httpd, hopefully?
- Is there a factual technical argument to be had with the this service provider about the merit of this issue?

Comment: Do you actually use `mod_lua`?

Comment: Great question, @Stephen Kitt. I don't know, but I will turn it off on a test instance and see what happens.

Comment: I'm not sure that question #2 is Answerable, in the spirit of this site.

Comment: Yes, thanks, @Jeff Schaller, I reworded the question. But I think I am all set. Disabled mod_lua and filed another dispute.

Answer (score 0):

I just turned this module off, by commenting out the LoadModule line in the `00-lua.conf` file. Thanks, @[Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt)